# Could Mars be punched onto a collision course with Earth?

Tags: science-based, planets

In a fantasy world I am making someone insanely powerful is knocked into space and lands on Mars. He can't just jump back because there are people who can push him off course and he would be going through space forever.

Instead he calculates the right time and area and punches Mars so hard it sets it on a crash course for earth, the punch also destroys most of it so only the iron core arrives. It goes at a speed that it would hit the earth in about 300 years at the shortest distance, so lets just say about 21kmph.

Disregarding where the power comes from, is it possible? I am assuming that realistically, the energy to do that focused on one point wouldn't push it all in one direction and would instead blow the planet up so its impossible for it to get to the earth in any big pieces.

Comment: If I were that guy I would jump towards earth with a huge boulder on my shoulders and if I do indeed go off course I'd use the boulder in a course adjustment chuck like a mass ejection propellant, or only chuck pieces of it to prevent over correction.

Comment: I think the punch of such force, besides such side-effects as immediately vacating the hero from the premises of the solar system, would just obliterate Mars into a debris cloud. No iron cores would survive - at planetary scales literally anything behaves like a liquid.

Comment: The core of Mars is liquid anyway, going by Insight's findings.

Comment: You could get around the problem of the hero being ejected at near light speed by instead having the hero throw some large boulder at near light speed. The physics works out to be the same but it would be the boulder carrying away Mar's Δp rather than the hero (though I rather suspect the hero + bits of Mars would just punch through the entire planet rather than moving the planet much.)

Comment: You might get some interesting ideas if you asked a different question e.g. My insanely strong and indestructible (think Superman, but can't fly) character is stuck on Mars and wants to get back to Earth, but can't just jump there because etc. How might he get safely back to Earth?

Comment: @Spike0xff actually everything else is taken into account as a big part of the story already. whats left of mars about to hit earth is actually stopped and held in orbit around the earth and becomes a second moon which is relevant to the plot. its also important that it takes hundreds of years for it to arrive and even more years for the punching guy to eventually land on another object and jump all the way back to earth once its safe. Its more about how he sends a giant moon sized object to hit the earth rather than how he gets back.

Comment: Can you first resolve "someone insanely powerful… can't just jump back because there are people who can push him off course and he would be going through space forever…"? Won't half your readership have already accepted, as Hollywood has, that Archimedes was correct to say a lever long enough and place to put it could move the Earth

Slipping some details under the gloss is the world builder's raison d'etre.

Comment: Might I suggest a hidden/unmentioned superpower of your hero? That everything he applies his superstrength to gains an appropriate amount of structural integrity and atomic cohesion? It's basically the only kind of explanation for why superman can keep an airplane from crashing by pushing against its nose without ripping through the very same plane he's trying to stop. Could also be selective, so that he can move what he wants and destroy what he wants as is applicable.

Comment: I thought this is world building, not world destroying

Comment: The answers point out that by Newton's third law of dynamics, a humanoid character cannot punch Mars into the Earth. However, consider this: the character first splits Mars into two halves. Then, positioning themselves between the two halves, they push one half towards the Earth, and the other half into the opposite direction.

Comment: @sociocat `Its more about how he sends a giant moon sized object to hit the earth rather than how he gets back.` That's a completely different question than this one, and (IMO) a more likely to be answered ("more answerable"?) one

Comment: @JoshPart yeah true, I guess I felt like something like that is too big to be trying to get the idea from people online instead of making it myself, but now that I think about it you are right. is it different enough that I can make a new post about it?

Comment: 21 km/h ? Nice to know I can reach Mars on my bicycle in 300 years !

Comment: All the hero is going to do is pole holes in mars, his surface area is far to small to impart any significant force.

Answer (score 28):

Can I paraphrase Nietzsche while quoting Newton's third law of dynamics?

> When you punch the abyss, the abyss punches you too

What is the difference between jumping and punching? When you jump you basically kick the ground so hard that your body is sent up by the reaction. Same would hold for this punching case.

But let's look at some numbers, just for the fun of it: Mars orbital velocity is around 25 km/s, and its mass is $6.4 \cdot  10^{24}$ kg, therefore its momentum is $M^{'}_{Mars}\times v^{'}_{Mars} =$$160 \cdot  10^{27}$ kgm/s.

Your hero wants to punch it away at 21 kmh, or 5.9 m/s. It would need to impart therefore $M_{Mars}\times v_{Mars} =$$37.8 \cdot  10^{24}$ kgm/s. Assuming a punch duration of 0.1 s, your hero would be subject to a force of $F = M_{Mars}\times v_{Mars}/\Delta t =$$37.8 \cdot  10^{25}$ N. Even if his mass was 1000 kg (a bulky guy, for sure) he would be accelerating at $F/m=$ $37.8 \cdot  10^{22} \ m/s^2$, or $10^{21}$ gee.

This means that, in a Newtonian universe ignoring relativity effects, in 1 s he would be $s=1/2at^2=$$10^{22}$ meters from the punching point. For a reference, 1 AU is $10^{11}$ meters.

If you want the relativistic effects, look at [Adrian's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/217700/30492).

Comment: If anybody can chip in the relativistic calculation, I will gladly add it to the answer

Comment: For reference, the size of the known Universe is $8.8 × 10^{26} m$. The _Newtonian_ superman would be out of the known Universe in a wee little more than 1 day. Now we're speaking of going places...

Comment: "If anybody can chip in the relativistic calculation, I will gladly add it to the answer" If you want to [copy pasta it](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/217700/edit) be my guest, I don't have enough power left to contextualize. (if you do take it, I'll hapilly delete mine)

Comment: The biggest difference between jumping and punching is the way energy is imparted and released. Jumping, the body's uses stored energy and releases it over time. Once discharged, the momentum of the body exceeds the pull of gravity, for just a moment. A punch, the energy is transferred to the arm in a very short time. Its just awaiting a target to transfer that energy to come in contact. Once contacted, energy is then distributed immediately. A better analogy is a punch and the act of landing after a jump.

Comment: I did expect that the punch would make him go backwards, but I didn't expect it to be going that far backwards, that's very fast.

Comment: While amusing, I feel like this (and the other current answers) don't actually answer the question posed. The question wasn't about what would happen to the hero, but whether Mars could be made to arrive at Earth via punch.

Comment: @sociocat:  The speed discrepancy is so large because the superhero is much much much smaller than Mars.  The ratio of their speeds is (more or less) the same as the ratio of their masses.

Comment: I dont know if I should edit my post to change the question or make a new post but how different would it be if instead of mars, it was the dwarf planet Ceres?

Comment: @sociocat, that's not really a new question. You just need to change the values in the formulas, which I am going to add for clarity

Comment: @L.Dutch thanks, I just want to know if it would be any closer to working than if he used Mars, but part of me thinks it still wont be. is there a way to make it more reasonable if it move at a slower speed but he keeps going back multiple times? maybe just the energy required to push Ceres out of orbit and not make it go very fast towards earth exactly. thank you for your help

Comment: @sociocat, look at the comment of Michael Seifert above

Comment: At 10E21g he needs to start to worry about Unruh radiation, though I think it would only be around 40K at that acceleration.

Answer (score 23):

There's this temptation to consider the change in Mars' kinetic energy as totally transferred into our hero kinetic energy. But, you see, this is not to be *that* simple. Yes, the total energy is conserved, but Mars gets smashed in the process and a lot of energy gets lost as heat, kinetic energy of the Mars fragments flying mad through the solar system and beyond.

Fortunately, the momentum does conserve in the smashing and since the reckless hero remains intact, he'll end taking the variation of momentum Mars got rid of. There's a problem here as well, since the momentum is a vector, so the direction in which the hero smashes Mars will matter. To simplify, lets say what he chose to do is to punch Mars straight in the face; I mean that one face that happened to be in the direction of Mars' way on its orbit.

As a result, Mars speed drops from 25km/s on 21km/s (the correct way to put it is: "the speed of Mars' barycenter etc" since now Mars is in tatters, but never mind). The variation of its momentum is $\Delta p_{Mars} =  160⋅{10}^{27} kg⋅m/s$ and this will be the momentum $p$ of the dumb hero after he's done the deed.

The relativistic impulse

$$p = \frac{m_0⋅v}{\sqrt{1-{(\frac{v}{c})}^2}} = \frac{m_0⋅c⋅\frac{v}{c}}{\sqrt{1-{(\frac{v}{c})}^2}}$$

We're interested in $\frac{v}{c}$ so square up everything

$$p^2 = \frac{{(m_0⋅c)}^2⋅(\frac{v}{c})^2}{1-{(\frac{v}{c})}^2}$$

Introduce the notation of  $\alpha = \frac{m_0⋅c}{p}$ and get:

$$\frac{1}{\alpha^2} = \frac{(\frac{v}{c})^2}{1-{(\frac{v}{c})}^2}$$ and thus

$$\frac{v}{c} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+{\alpha}^2}}$$

Now, you see, there a big problem, because a hero of any mass less than a planetary body will make $\alpha$ so small, not even its mother will recognize it.

I mean, look, I'll go way further than [L.Dutch](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/217687/26061) and set the idiot hero's mass to $10^9kg$ - that's as much mass as the water in one cubic kilometer. Or, if you prefer it in more comprehensible units, that's as much water as in 400 Olympic sizes swimming pools. Be the hero as much beyond pathological obese as he is, still makes:

$$\alpha = 299792458m/s⋅10^9kg/160⋅10^{27}kg⋅m/s = 1.8737029⋅10^{-12}$$

And the problem that we have: any reasonable calculator will tell us that

$$\frac{v}{c} = \frac{1}{1+(1.8737029⋅10^{-12})^2} = 1$$

for all practical purposes. But what the heck, I'm far from reasonable, so I simple **need** to know how many $9$ after that $0.$ can I get. So, Maxima to the rescue for a Taylor expansion ($ev(taylor(sqrt(1/(1+x^2)),x,0,6), keepfloat)$ if you really want to know), so

$$\frac{v}{c} \approx 1-\frac{\alpha^2}{2}+\frac{3⋅\alpha^4}{8}-\frac{5⋅\alpha^6}{16}+...$$

If I'm discarding all the terms with a power higher or equal to 4, I should have at least 46 exact digits ($(1.8737029⋅10^{-12})^4 = 1.2325454⋅10^{-47}$).

So $$\frac{v}{c} \approx 1 - \frac{(1.8737029⋅10^{-12})^2}{2} = 0.99999999999999999999999...$$ - that's 23 pure unadulterated $9$s after that $0.$ (because $\frac{(1.8737029⋅10^{-12})^2}{2} = 1.7553813⋅10^{-24}$, so at least 23 exact digits, with a possible discrepancy on the 24'th decimal place).

<sup>Now, I can get to sleep</sup>

Comment: That is a lot of math but what do all the 9s represent?

Comment: The poor guy is traveling so close to the speed of light that his relative height in direction of travel makes a razor blade tip look like a mountain. Fortunately, he's also slowed down time-wise so much that he barely has time to notice before he's out of the galaxy.

Comment: @sociocat 1c would be the speed of light. So 0.999...999c is obscenely close to the speed of light for a physical being

Comment: There's also a slight open question where you get the energy to accelerate a billion kilograms to those speeds. That takes like a septillion kilograms of antimatter, if I got my powers of 10 right, and if the process is efficient. But of course it isn't; annihiliating antimatter mostly produces heat and radiation.

Comment: @NotEntirelySerious if my intuition is at least somewhat correct, our hero will, in their reference frame, be immediately bathed by cosmic microwave background blueshifted to deadly energies, as well as quite a lot of hydrogen atoms (also blueshifted to ridiculous masses), as well all of Mars's atmosphere in their path all at once. Since c-1e-24 is higher than the speed of nerve impulses, the good news they literally won't know what hit them. They simply cease to exist as a coherent structure.

Comment: For further reference: our hero would be traveling at just about the same speed as the OMG particle (whose relativistic mass was whooping 14 Joule / c^2 packed into a single proton)... speaking of which, I may have a new hypothesis regarding its origins.

Comment: At that speed, the apparent width of the earth in the direction of travel due to Lorentz Contraction is 0.00006 m. So, not only did he send mars flying towards Earth, he made them both flatter than pancakes (from his perspective).

Comment: And if I've done my calculations right, 1 second (in his own personal frame of reference) after the punch, our hero will now be 7085 light years from the solar system. So, assuming no loss of speed, and going the long way through the galaxy, he'll leave the galaxy in less than 10 seconds. That was where he wanted to be, right?

Answer (score 9):

Even if Mars were to be solid granite, or diamond for that matter, there is no material with sufficient stiffness to resist deformation when subject to a nearly infinite force.  It would be like punching a cloud.

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible for someone to "punch" Mars to change course, because **each force produces an equal force in the opposite direction**. Means if there was a punch hard enough to do so, the opposite force would let your protagonist "jump" with the same energy, making him fly in the opposite direction much faster, probably near the speed of light! And this not even closely touching on mechanics of materials reacting to such forces.

Thus, it would require some kind of mass that can be ejected in the opposite direction. Then, it would be possible to move mars, even though it would require ridiculous amount of energy, which to produce would take many millenia with current or near-future human technology.

Comment: Its actually part of the plan that hes pushed backwards and lands on a different object, but the force required to punch mars that hard would make him go near the speed of light like you said, and would probably be flying with enough force that he would blast through any planet. I guess that means there isnt really a rational way to make it happen. Also, the story has magic so his strength is just explained with that.

Comment: @sociocat:  If the story has magic, you could just say that magic doesn't obey Newton's Third Law.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert His magic just gives him as much physical strength as is needed to accomplish his goals, hes not using magic directly on the planet. He already has power that defies rules and has a reason for having a power that strong, I dont want to defy more rules just to help the plot.

Answer (score 7):

Apart from the core being liquid and the many other mechanical issues with punching Mars to move it: Mars and Earth are both orbiting the sun, and the sun's gravity makes it impossible to just go in a straight line that hits Earth after 300 years (after all, it's enough to swing Earth in a complete circle 300 times in that time). At most, the remains of Mars hit Earth after 8-9 months. Short of that, they just end up in an elliptical orbit that doesn't even cross Earth's orbit.

That elliptical orbit may be unstable enough to eventually hit Earth due to the gravitational perturbations of Earth and the other planets, but this is extremely sensitive to the exact starting conditions, and thousands or millions of years might be a more realistic timescale.

In any case, it won't hit at 21 km/h, it'll hit at somewhat over 40000 km/h. That's the escape velocity for Earth's surface, and also the impact velocity for anything falling to Earth from a large distance. Is it his intention to convert Earth into a molten ball of rock with a slightly larger iron-nickel core? Because that's about what would happen.

Comment: Well in the story theres only one other person that has the power to push him off course if he tries to jump back to earth, punching a planet towards the earth would force that person to use all his energy and probably die to keep them from colliding. The person who punched the planet would be flying backwards from the punch and land on another object like one of Jupiter's moons, and after landing would be able to make a jump back to earth with nothing stopping him once he returns. however other people pointed out he would be going so fast he would probably burst through anything.

Comment: Punch, kick, jump, whatever they do gives themselves exactly the same momentum as they give the planet, and far more kinetic energy. If the other party is put at risk by a planet thrown by this guy, they're in even more trouble trying to intercept them directly. Apart from that, how would the Earth-bound defender even be aware they're returning, let alone spot them far enough away to interfere? And apart from *that*, how are these people just _jumping_ with enough precision to hit other celestial bodies?

Comment: Well the world has magic and those two people, a sun god and war god, were both very intelligent astronomers. it was during a time where telescopes werent invented so instead they developed the magic ability to use their eyes like telescopes and see things extremely far away. The war god became strong enough that he couldnt be killed so with the help of other gods, the sun god blast him into space. The war god kept track of his trajectory and cut out and threw his own blood to change direction to steer himself towards mars.

Comment: However you are right, if he has the power to punch a planet that hard he would have the power to jump at light speed towards the earth and that would be impossible to stop. also mentioning might not be working

Answer (score 1):

I'm following Christopher James Huff direction of thinking.

1. Mars and Earth orbit the Sun. A single blow can't put Mars into path where it would gradually decrease its distance to Earth for 300 years.
2. One could attempt to put Mars onto an eccentric orbit intersecting with Earth's orbit. That would require a knock of velocity of at last **2500 km/h** (calculations below), thus quite some more than 21 km/h. Mars would then intersect the Earth's orbit in less than a year. Depending on the initial positions of the planets on their orbits the collision could occur during the first intersection or one of the further ones. If however they would not collide for 300 years, the Earth's orbit could be still perturbed by the gravitational force of Mars, which by itself could have catastrophic results. Predicting the details would require a complex simulation.
3. If you want to postpone the collision for 300 years, I would propose to knock Mars *away* from the Sun, so it would cross Neptune's orbit and come back after 300 years to hit the Earth. One still would need to take into account possible interactions of Mars with the outer planets and perform very precise calculations, but that might be easier than keeping Mars just next to the Earth without a collision for 300 years. The knock velocity to the planet would need to exceed **11500 km/h** so even more. An advantage of this method is that depending on the planets position the recoil may put the protagonist into virtually any spot in the solar system you want, including the Earth or its Moon.
4. As the others pointed out, if the protagonist transfers momentum to the planet, it receives the same momentum in the opposite direction. For 2500 km/h knock on Mars a 100kg protagonist would receive energy of 16·10¹⁵ GeV  per each nucleus of his body. This is a lot. That's way more than any energy ever produced in laboratory or observed in nature. That's a hypothesized energy of Grand Unification (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_unification_energy). The act of knocking would be extremely violent. Complete disintegration of any molecular and nuclear structures, production of any known and perhaps unknown particles, maybe even black holes.
5. Some suggested that the knock would destroy the planet. Maybe. The energy of the knock described in point 2 is 39·10³⁰ J, while Mars binding energy is perhaps 5·10³⁰ J. Some  matter would follow in the desired direction. It's difficult for me to speculate how exactly it would turn out.
6. Once the protagonist lands on another target planet or moon, it transfers its momentum to it, causing similar level of destruction and orbital perturbation as that done to Mars. As the others pointed out, it would violently interact with any matter on its way, and even with cosmic background (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greisen%E2%80%93Zatsepin%E2%80%93Kuzmin_limit).

---

Maths. I'm sorry if there are any mistakes, but note we're in the regime where adding or deleting a zero wouldn't change the conclusions.

2. **Knocking Mars towards the Earth** The total (potential and kinetic) energy of a planet with mass *m* orbiting around a star with mass *M* is
   $$E = -G\frac{Mm}{2a},$$
   where *a* is the semi-major axis.

Assuming Mars following a circular orbit, $a=R_\mathrm{Mars}$ (distance between Mars and the Sun), $$E_\mathrm{Mars} = -187·10^{30} \mathrm{J}.$$

For elliptic orbit between the present Mars and Earth's orbits $a = (R_\mathrm{Mars} + R_\mathrm{Earth})/2$, $$E_\mathrm{Mars-Earth} = -226·10^{30} \mathrm{J}. $$

The knock corresponds to change of the energy by $$\Delta E = E_\mathrm{Mars-Earth} - E_\mathrm{Mars} = -39·10^{30} \mathrm{J}.$$ As the potential energy remains constant, $\Delta E$ corresponds to change of the kinetic energy only.

The orbital velocity of Mars is $v_\mathrm{Mars} = 86430$ km/h, it's initial kinetic energy is $E_\mathrm{k} = mv_\mathrm{Mars}^{2}/2$, and final kinetic energy (just after the knock) is
$$E_\mathrm{k} + \Delta{E} = m\frac{(v_\mathrm{Mars} + \Delta v)^{2}}{2}.$$
The knock must change Mars velocity by
$$\Delta v = \sqrt{v_\mathrm{Mars}^{2} + \frac{2\Delta E}{m}} - v_\mathrm{Mars} = -\boldsymbol{2526 \mathrm{km/h}}$$

Note I assume a knock parallel to the Mars present velocity. A knock in another direction would require larger knock velocity.

3. **Knocking Mars away from the Earth**

Orbital period *T* can be calculated as:
$$T^2 = \frac{4\pi^2a^3}{GM}$$

If we want to kick Mars away from the Sun, and come back in 300 years and hit the Earth, we seek an orbit with T ≈ 300 years, and $a = (R_\mathrm{Earth} + R_2)/2$. We obtain
$$R_2 = \sqrt[3]{\frac{2T^2GM}{\pi^2}} - R_\mathrm{Earth} = 13·10^{9} \mathrm{km}.$$
For comparison, Neptune orbit is 30·10⁹ km.

Nice reference for orbital formulae:
https://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/152.mf1i.spring02/EllipticOrbits.htm

4. **Impact on the protagonist** (and generally the energy considered during the knock).

The knock changes Mars momentum by

$$|\Delta p| = |m\cdot\Delta v| = 450·10^{24} \mathrm{kg·m·s}^{-1}.$$

The protagonist gains the same momentum in the opposite direction. The mass of the human body, or the matter around us in general, is dominated by the mass of the nucleons. Let's assume the hero weighs $m_\mathrm{H} = 100$ kg. There are $n$ nucleons in his body, each weighing $m_\mathrm{N} \approx 0.938$ GeV/c² and $n = m_\mathrm{H}/m_\mathrm{N}$.

Since $|\Delta p| = \gamma m_\mathrm{H} c$ we can calculate momentum per nucleon
$$\frac{|\Delta p|}{n\cdot c} = 16·10^{15} \mathrm{GeV/c}.$$
Since we're in ultra relativistic regime, energy equals the momentum. $E = \boldsymbol{16·10^{15} \mathrm{GeV}}$ (this is energy of each nucleon in the protagonist body).

5. **Destruction of Mars**

Binding energy of a uniform sphere is
$$U=-\frac{3GM^2}{5R} = \boldsymbol{4.8·10^{30} \mathrm{J}}$$
for Mars. Planets are not uniform spheres, they have denser core, so the binding energy is higher, but we are clearly in the energy range where destruction of the planet can happen.

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_binding_energy

Comment: that is very informative, and the idea for putting it into an orbit where it collides with earth eventually is a very good idea. overall, even if I ignored the insane power that would push the punching guy back, its clear that you cant move a planet that significantly without blowing it up. id ask if its possible to move a planet at all without destroying it as only one person with infinite strength but thats another question and youve done a lot of work already. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at the implications of Adrian Colomitchi's answer:

The guy goes flying off exceedingly close to lightspeed.  The fist doing the punching is moving even faster.  Note that at this point are talking about energies that make the beam  of the LHC look like the blackness between the stars in comparison.

The matter he strikes is turned into a sea of ultra-energetic particles which will spread the energy about.  The kinetic energy still ends up transferred into the planet but very spectacularly.  Unfortunately, the energy thus delivered is higher than the binding energy of Mars.  The planet is shattered, there isn't going to be a core heading for Earth.

Comment: "Unfortunately, the energy thus delivered is higher than the binding energy of Mars. " Numbers, please. He leaves with a significant amount of energy, after all (that is, assuming that his entire self doesn't just actually punch a hole his size from one side of the planet to the other)

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Simple shortcut:  Binding energy is approximately 60% of the energy to simply move the planet to infinity of itself.  Compare the velocity imparted vs the escape velocity.